# Data gathering on Rpi from arduino using serial port and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, arduino, raspberry-pi, usb

im making an arduino program that sends some sensors data to a Raspberry pi model 3 by USB

I also made a python script to log this data to the Raspberry and a SQL Base

The arduino sends a 1 to know when to take the first value, the rPi script changes the mode from 0 to 1 and then starts reading the 4 values, here is when the problem comes, as the rPi dont notices the 1 and never changes to mode 1

Heres the python code:

```
while True:
    while mode==0:
        x = ser.readline()
        if x==1:
            //never gets here
            print("b")
            mode = 1
            print("Starting data Gathering at rPi from arduino")

    while mode==1:
        print("Gathering data")
        text1 = "CFL"
        ignore1 = ser.readline()
        x1 = ser.readline()
        x1 = double(x1)
        x2 = ser.readline()
        x2 = double(x2)
        y = ser.readline()
        y = int(y)
        z = ser.readline()
        z = int(z)  
        time1 = time.time()
        date1 = time.strftime('%d-%m-%d')
        print("Saving sql data")
        sql = "INSERT INTO tempdat(tdate, ttime, zone, DHTtemp, DHThum, SoilHum, Light) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d)" %(date1,time1,text1,x1,x2,y,z)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
```

And the arduino one:

```
void loop() {

    Serial.println(1);

    Serial.println(read_temp());
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(read_humidity_DHT());
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(read_humidity_soil()); 
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(read_light());
    delay(10000);
}
```

Also would love to ask if somebody knows, the best way to tag the info i send to know on the rPi from which sensors comes from. Thanks in advance

*edit some code was badly copied when creating question

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.println` sends ASCII code followed by `\r\n`. You are comparing ASCII characters with integer value. Try this:

```
    x = ''
    while ser.inWaiting():
        c=ser.read()
        if c not in "\r\n":
            x += c
    if x=='1':
    . . .
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response, ive tried it and dont works neither, i put a print() in the while ser.inWaiting() bucle just before the ser.read() and never reaches it, I also thought htere must be some Variable type conflict, but i suposed readLine() returns a String, but seems it dont, as i've also tried   comparing is as String                                                  x = ser.readline()
        if x=="1":       and dont work neither

Answer (score 0):

Put a break statement, so you are never leaving the first loop.